# What exactly is Java type long long

Tags: java, long-integer

I know in Java that "int" is a 32 bit integer and that "long" is a 64 integer. I also know that in C "long long" is an integer at least as large as "long" (but implementation specific).

However I have recently come across some Java code using "long long" and wanted to know how exactly it was defined?

Comment: I know this is old, but I had the same question and it seems, also from a  test.  Here is the code: int equi(int arr[], int n) {
    if (n==0) return -1; 
    long long sum = 0;
    int i; 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) sum+=(long long) arr[i]; 

    long long sum_left = 0;    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        long long sum_right = sum - sum_left - (long long) arr[i];
        if (sum_left == sum_right) return i;
        sum_left += (long long) arr[i];
    } 
    return -1; 
}

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no such type in Java.  Are you sure the code you read was written in Java?  Maybe it was a JNI routine that was called into?

Comment: Apologies code was supplied as the answer to a Java programming test, but it appears to have been written in C.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know a type called "long long".

it isn't also listed here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 1):

"long long" not supported  in java

Comment: In java we just use long that support 64 bit width , like as in for c++(long long)

Answer (score 0):

It support 
int-16bit
long-32bit
for big number calculation you can use long as well as int .